# Hatching Package with Metapost

Tags: pdftex, metapost

I am new in metapost and I am unsure as to re-define the **withcolor** command to revert back to the metapost default.

I am trying to draw the cross section of a cylinder, where the inner circle is empty, but the outer marked with straight lines.

Can you please help me? I am very tight with time!

This is the code so far:

```
input hatching;

u := 1cm;
path circle; 
circle = fullcircle scaled 10u;
outputtemplate:="%j%c.mps";
beginfig(1); 
hatchfill circle withcolor (45, 5mm, -.5bp);
draw circle;
draw fullcircle scaled 5u; % This needs to be filled with color white
endfig;
end
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Save the inner circle as a path first, unfill it and then draw it.

```
input hatching;

u := 1cm;
path circle; 
circle = fullcircle scaled 10u;
outputtemplate:="%j%c.mps";
beginfig(1); 
hatchfill circle withcolor (45, 5mm, -.5bp);
draw circle;
path inner_circle;
inner_circle := fullcircle scaled 5u; % This needs to be filled with color white
unfill inner_circle;
draw inner_circle;
endfig;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you daleif for your fast. I was unaware of the unfill command! You made my afternoon.

Comment: At the other end, I did not know about `hatching`

Comment: Haha. Give and receive!