# METAPOST: a bug with clip

Tags: metapost

It seems that

```
clip currentpicture to p;
```

not only clips the picture to `p`, but also sets its the bounds in an unpredictable way.

Here is a MWE:

```
filenametemplate "%j-%1c.png";
outputformat := "png";
beginfig(1);
save u;
u:=1cm;

draw (-1,-1)*u--(-10,10)*u--(10,10)*u--cycle withcolor (87, 1mm, -.5bp);
clip currentpicture to (-10,-10)*u--(-10,0)*u--(10,0)*u--(10,-10)*u--cycle;

endfig;
end
```

The produced picture has wide empty space on its right and left, (the vertical size is as expected):

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “right”?

Comment: @egreg the size should be calculated ignoring empty space (as it happens usually).

Comment: OT: that color definition is a bit weird....

Comment: @Aditya the `withcolor` appears to be left over from one used with the [`hatching`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161494/15036) package.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong here.  It has set the bounds to the overlap of the `bbox` of the `currentpicture` and the path that you have given.  What else where you expecting?  That it would automatically shrink the bbox after it has done the `clip`?

Comment: If you want to adjust the resulting `bbox` you should probably use `setbounds`...

Comment: @Thruston is there a way to get rid of the white space automatically? --- without looking at the picture and/or making calculations.

Comment: Nothing built in - but you could write a macro to iterate over all the elements of the image, and `setbounds` accordingly.   What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Thruston, Usually metapost calculates the size automatically ignoring white space --- that is what I want and expect in this case, but you say it not easy --- so let's forget about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is a mismatch between the OP expectation, and what Metapost actually does with a `clip` command.  If you examine the source code — in particular the `mp_set_bbox` function in [`mp.w`](https://serveur-svn.lri.fr/svn/modhel/metapost/trunk/source/texk/web2c/mplibdir/mp.w) — you will find that the introductory comment says:

> @ The major difficulty in finding the bounding box of an edge structure is the
> effect of clipping paths.  We treat them conservatively by only clipping to the
> clipping path's bounding box, but this still requires recursive calls to
> `set_bbox` in order to find the bounding box of the objects to be clipped.
> Such calls are distinguished by the fact that the boolean parameter `top_level`
> is false.

And this is exactly what has happened in this case.  The OP started of with a V-shaped path, constructed in such a way that the `bbox` of this path was approximately a 10cm square.  This was then clipped to another 10cm square, shifted down about 9 cm.  The result is a picture with a `bbox` that is the overlap of these two squares -- a rectangle approx 10x1cm with the bottom of the V-shape in the middle of it.

I guess there was an original design trade off here, and the designers of MP decided to keep things simple, and let the users of the language work out how to deal with edge cases for themselves.